# Virtual keyboard character for Malay and Indonesian

Tags: jquery, virtual-keyboard

I am using virtual keyboard  http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/.
Here, I am able to get the virtual keyboard for languages like English, Chinese etc. But the plugin dont have virtual keyboard for **Malaysian and Indonesian**.
I googled for hours, but didnot get any script for these languages.
Is there any source to get unicode character script (with special character) in javascript or jquery these langueges?

Comment: Maybe you can try making your own keyboard layout? Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Contributing). It doesn't seem very difficult.

Comment: Also take a look at [some existing layouts](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/tree/master/layouts).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am able to create custom script file. But I dont know Indonesian and Malaysian characters. So, is there any source from where I can get the alphabet characters with special characters for these language ? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know either of those languages. [Maybe this wiki article could help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_alphabet).

Comment: I already visited this link . Anyway, Mottie clarified my doubts. Thank you alan0xd7 for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a list of keyboard layout sources to the plugin [home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki#keyboard-layout-references).

Anyway, it appears that the [Indonesian layout](http://ascii-table.com/keyboard.php/103P-2) is a standard qwerty layout.

And since [Malaysia has so many different languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Malaysia), I don't think one specific layout will cover it. Although, at the bottom of the info box on the right of that wikipedia page, a [UK keyboard layout is shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Malaysia#/media/File:KB_United_Kingdom.svg).